# Refactor code with return statements

Tags: java, refactoring

The "if" blocks with checkcustomers are exactly used in other methods in this class, so there is a lot of code dublication for same checks. But I cant also directly extract this checksomethings to one single method because they have return values.

Some good ideas to refactor this code? I just modified this code to simplify here, so dont get caught on minor issues in this code(if any), Basically question is how to a extract a piece of code to a method(because it is dublicated on other methods) when there are many returns in that current method.

```
public Details getCustomerDetails(){

   if(checkifcustomerhasnoboobs){    
    ..worry about it..
   return new Details("no");
  }

   if(checkifcustomerplaytenniswell){    
    ..do find a tennis teacher
    return new Details("no cantplay");
  }
  //...ok now if customer passed the test, now do the some real stuff
  //
  //
  CustomerDetails details= getCustomerDetailsFromSomewhere();

  return details;

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that your "checksomethings" are repeated? If so these are business rules which means you could extract them out into a method and simply call the method from different places.

Comment: To expanp on BrianC's suggestion. You could have a generic validate() method that returned a Details object.  You could say that if it returned null, everything is fine, otherwise return the Details object in the calling method.

Comment: Whenever I find myself doing these sorts of things, I find that polymorphism is generally the answer. I would imagine in this case, you would have an interface with `getDetails()` and each scenario would have an implementation (in this case, 2 implementations: error1 and error2). Then a Map<K,V> to house these implementations where the key is what you use in checksomething and the value is the implementation.

Comment: @cklab tnx udpated the Q

Comment: @Spring I don't understand why you are unable to extract this just because it has return values. If it doesn't fit any of those `if`s, you can return null from the extracted method to signify that the customer passed the test. It's very difficult to suggest the "best practice" here because we are only exposed to a small portion of the code. I have no idea how all these objects interact with each other.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
public Result checkSomethings() {
  if ( checksomething1 ) {
    return ResultCheckSomething1;
  }
  if ( checksomething2 ) {
    return ResultCheckSomething2;
  }
  return ResultCheckNone;
}

public Details getCustomerDetails(){
  Result result = checkSomethings();
  switch ( result ) {
    case ResultCheckSomething1:
      return new Details("message1");
    case ResultCheckSomething2:
      return new Details("message2");
    default:
      return getCustomerDetailsFromSomewhere();
  }
}
```

The `Result...` codes would be in an enum.

Comment: I mean "enum Result { ResultCheckSomething1, ResultCheckSomething2 }" or something like that to define the return values.

Comment: srry I didnt understand what u r exactly trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
   public Details getCustomerDetails(){
       boolean isError = checksomething1() || checksomething2();
       String message = checksomething1() ? "message1" : "message2";
       return isError ? new Details(message) : getCustomerDetailsFromSomewhere();
}
```

If you try to avoid call check functions twice just keep it results

```
public Details getCustomerDetails(){
   boolean check1 = checksomething1();
   boolean check2 = checksomething2();
   String message = check1 ? "message1" : "message2";
   return (check1 || check2) ? new Details(message) : getCustomerDetailsFromSomewhere();
```

}

Comment: I'd try to avoid calling checksomething1() twice.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the returns with assignments to a result variable that remains null until the first assignment to it. Each block could be replaced by a function that returns null if its condition for changing the result is false.

As pointed out in a comment by herman, this only works if null is not a possible result of one of calls.

```
public Details getCustomerDetails(){
   Details result = null;

   if(checksomething1){    
    ..error
     result = new Details("message1");
  }

  if(result == null) {
    if(checksomething2){    
    ..error
    result = new Details("message2");
  } 

  if(result == null){

    result = getCustomerDetailsFromSomewhere();
  }

  return result;

}
```

Comment: This is only possible if the return statements in the code to be extracted cannot return null.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
public Details getCustomerDetails(){  

  Details invalidDetails = checkForInvalidCustomer();
  if (invalidDetails !=null) {
     return (invalidDetails);
  }

  //...ok now if customer passed the test, now do the some real stuff
  //
  //
  CustomerDetails details= getCustomerDetailsFromSomewhere();
  return details;
}

public Details checkForInvalidCustomer() {
   if(checkifcustomerhasnoboobs){    
    ..worry about it..
    return new Details("no");
   }
   if(checkifcustomerplaytenniswell){    
    ..do find a tennis teacher
    return new Details("no cantplay");
  }
  // nulls means valid customer
  return (null);
}
```

Basically, for your specific example, I'm using null so that I can differentiate the case where none of the conditions matched, vs either condition matched. That way I can use a single if statement. Now, if you wanted to return null, you would need to modify this solution slightly, perhaps use some constant for flagging the case instead of using null.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8, you can refactor into a method that returns an `Optional<...>` value.
Statements like `return x;` would be replaced by `return Optional.of(x)` (assuming x cannot be null).  The default return statement at the end would be `return Optional.empty()`.

Then you can use `return optional.orElseGet(() -> ...))` to compute the value for the case where none of the original return statements would be reached.